# What happens if you are trained in a skill twice?

Tags: the-strange, cypher-system

Many of the Foci give free skill training.

Eg

> #### Trick or Treats (p210: Worlds Numberless and Strange)
>
> Tier 1: Treat Seeker. You are trained in tasks related to searching and hiding.
> Enabler. ....
>  Tier 2: Trick Artist. You are trained in lockpicking
> and tinkering with devices. Enabler...

Many Descriptors give Skill Training. All character types give skill training.
Some Recursion traits give skill training to everyone who is in them.

And of course you can take training in a skill by spend XP (indeed you have to, to up-tier).

What happens when these overlap?

I assume the first instance you become Specialized?

What about in the third instance, or if you are already specialized?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From page 21 of The Strange Core:

> Remember that if you gain a skill that you’re already trained in, you
>   become specialized in that skill. Because skill descriptions can be
>   nebulous, determining whether you’re trained or specialized might take
>   some thinking. For example, if you’re trained in lying and later gain
>   a benefit that grants you skill with all social interactions, you
>   become specialized in lying and trained in all other types of
>   interactions. Being trained three times in a skill is no better than
>   being trained twice (in other words, specialized is as good as it
>   gets).

Answer (score 0):

There was one supplement where they clarified that this "trained twice equals skilled" explicitly does NOT apply to attack skills. As in, this was an unstated assumption that was part of the balancing of the focuses and such.

A very strong claim can be made that this should also apply to "speed defense" -- skilled in speed defense normally only shows up at tier 5 or 6, and getting trained twice is easy at tier 2.

But for everything else? Trained twice = skilled. Trained three times = still skilled, but the GM should give you something else to make up for the otherwise wasted ability.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! What supplement was that in?

Comment: I no longer remember. Just that it was a clarification made by either Monte Cooke or Bruce, and I don't remember which one of them did it.